# Is it poor practice, or possibly error-prone, to read the contents of a PHP file that is currently running?

Tags: php

I've been using this method for years, and I've never run into an issue; however, it's always sort of nagged at me as to whether or not this is good practice. I'll cover what I'm doing specifically first and then provide background to the reasoning after since I'm sure it will be questioned.

**Problem / Question**
I am using `file_get_contents` to retrieve the contents of the very script that is running. In essence:

```
<?php
/**
 * My PHP Script On Load
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */

class MyClass {

    public function __construct() {
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match('Version\: ([0-9\.]+)/s', file_get_contents(__FILE__), $matches)) {
            $version = $matches[1];
        }
    }

}

$class = new MyClass();
```

The above works, and out of thousands of page loads of my own use (and many tens of thousands of never hearing of errors that could stem from this), I've never had a problem doing this. I've just always wondered if either a) it's bad practice, or b) it has the possibility of causing an error.

**Background / Use-case**
Naturally the first question is going to be "Why don't you just put the version in the constructor?" Of course, I could, but I must have the plugin version at the top of the file in the comments as shown and the only reason I don't do that is so I don't have the possibility of forgetting to update one or the other. By having it one place, I never have to worry about a screw up, which if it made it to a release build, could cause major problems with the update system of the platform I'm working on.

I'm open to other ideas for how to approach this, aside from using a deployment/CI to automate the placement of the version number, which I've already considered and may implement at some point. But three things must be true: 1) the version must be commented out at the top of the file in the same format shown in the example, 2) I must be able to have version available to the PHP code within the very same file, 3) the class must be instantiated from within the same file.

Comment: Put `define("VERSION_MYCLASS", "3.3.9");` at the top of the file?

Comment: I don't think that meets my requirement of needing the version in the commented code. Perhaps I should've specified that it needs to be the exact format shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PHP function to retrieve just the comments: [ReflectionClass::getDocComment](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php). You can use it instead of reading the whole file. I'm not sure about how it works when the code is encoded as mentioned by @Iłya Bursov.

```
<?php
/**
 * My PHP Script On Load
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */

class MyClass {

    public function __construct() { 
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match('/Version\: ([0-9\.]+)/s', (new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__))->getDocComment(), $matches)) {
            $version = $matches[1];
        }
    }

}

$class = new MyClass();   

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as it is open ended question, just some thoughts:

1. for some projects php files must be encoded, for example with [zend guard](https://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard), this will break this scheme completely
2. reading whole file is not ideal, you can just read first 100-200 bytes of it instead
3. what about pre-processing before you upload to server? some script, which reads all files, comments and puts variable $version into class?

Comment: I hadn't made considerations for item 1, that does shed some light. Certainly #2 is a good point for optimization. Item 3 falls into my deployment category, which is on the table. I'm just wondering if there is another way to approach it without going to that level.